# Using styles in react for selecting className

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I noticed this code

```
               className={classNames(
                            'p-button-text p-button-container',
                            styles['summary-container__counter'],
                            {
                                [styles['summary-container__counter--justify-left']]: isEmpty(share?.sharePermissions),
                            },
                        )}
```

Is this code going to be same if I don't use styles?

```
className={classNames(
                            'p-button-text p-button-container summary-container__counter',
                            {
                               'summary-container__counter--justify-left': isEmpty(share?.sharePermissions),
                            },
                        )}
```

Where styles is `scss` file `import styles from './styles.module.scss';`

Comment: It depends on what `styles` is, but it's unlikely to have the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not the same. CSS modules create unique classnames to facilitate scoping of CSS. As such, using a classname directly defined in the CSS module will have no effect and it is necessary to access that key from the imported CSS module to get the actual global classname.

See also:

- https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules